# Оформление виджета Android

Tags: android, виджет, design, android-widgets

Всем добрый вечер. Как сделать подобное оформление виджета ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я в android очень сильно новичок, и совсем не понимаю в стилях, хотелось бы подробно, для чайников. Интересует именно фон гаджета, он что ли в прозрачном блоке с тенью. Как такое повторить ?

Comment: Гаджет (gadget)- это физическое, обычно электронное, устройство. То, что у вас на скриншоте, в терминах Android, называется виджет.

Comment: Ооой)) Да, я перепутал, спасибо !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так выглядит разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/sea_background"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_rounded"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded"
            android:layout_height="90dp">

        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"

            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

В разметке sea_background это картинка с морем. white_rounded вот такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

transparent_rounded такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#40ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Все отступы и значения в dp лучше переносить в dimen.xml и указывать в разметке ссылки на них. Цвета соответственно в colors.xml. В определении цвета первые 2 цифры - его прозрачность (00 - прозрачный, ff - непрозрачный).

Для ListView пишется адаптер и делается файл разметки одной строчки, в котором в горизонтальном LinearLayout размещается фотография и текст.